# Any Faster or Shorter way of doing this in vb?

Tags: vb.net, optimization

I have an app that checks if a user's input is within a text range from A - F, my code works fine but I just thought there should be a shorter way of doing this, in one line probably?

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub ResultButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ResultButton.Click

        Dim Range_A As Integer, Range_B As Integer, Range_C As Integer,
            Range_D As Integer, Range_E As Integer, Range_F As Integer, Range_Check As Integer

        Range_A = Integer.Parse(inputTextBox.Text)
        Range_B = Integer.Parse(inputTextBox.Text)
        Range_C = Integer.Parse(inputTextBox.Text)
        Range_D = Integer.Parse(inputTextBox.Text)
        Range_E = Integer.Parse(inputTextBox.Text)
        Range_F = Integer.Parse(inputTextBox.Text)

        Range_Check = Integer.Parse(inputTextBox.Text)

        If Range_Check >= 101 Or Range_Check < 0 Then

            MessageBox.Show(" Only values within 0 and 100 are allowed, please type a number within this range.")

        End If


        If Range_F >= 0 And Range_F <= 39 Then

            MessageBox.Show(" " & Range_F & " is within the F Range")
            Exit Sub

        End If

        If Range_E >= 40 And Range_E <= 44 Then

            MessageBox.Show(" " & Range_E & " is within the E Range")
            Exit Sub

        End If

        If Range_D >= 45 And Range_D <= 49 Then

            MessageBox.Show(" " & Range_D & " is within the D Range")
            Exit Sub

        End If

        If Range_C >= 50 And Range_C <= 59 Then

            MessageBox.Show(" " & Range_C & " is within the C Range")
            Exit Sub

        End If

        If Range_B >= 60 And Range_B <= 69 Then

            MessageBox.Show(" " & Range_B & " is within the B Range")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Range_A >= 70 And Range_A <= 100 Then

            MessageBox.Show(" " & Range_A & " is within the A Range")
            Exit Sub

        End If


    End Sub
```

I'm repeating the same `Integer.Parse` statements which last time I checked isn't always a good idea in progamming, how do I optimise these lines of code please?

Comment: I don't understand the idea behind your code. It looks like you are parsing the same textbox six time just to assign the same value to six different variables, which doesn't make much sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Agreed: could you show us what you actually do with Range_A, Range_B, etc?  Seems like you could just define a single variable Range and use it instead of Range_A etc.

Comment: I have an app in vb that accepts values between ranges A - F using integers from 1 - 100 typed into a textbox by the user, every range of numbers as alphabet grades, for example, 0 - 39 is A, 40 - 50 is B and so on, so when the user types a number within a particular range, the user gets a message box telling what alphabet range was typed in.

Comment: you need a CASE statement to determine the correct alpha bracket of the value; Integer.Parse is not doing that (it just converts "1" to 1).  Even then, a single Range variable which stored the A B C result is all you need.

Comment: @ChrisBogart Thanks, I have updated my question with the actual code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Dim range As String = ""
  If Not Integer.TryParse(inputTextBox.Text, theValue) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Enter only numerals, please")
        Exit Sub
  End if

  ' if integer,.tryparse is true then theValue will have the result

  Select Case theValue
      Case Is > 100, Is < 1
          ' do err msg

      Case 0 to 39
         range = "A"

      Case 40 To 50
         range = "B"

     ' etc...or:

      Case 41 to 44
            MessageBox.Show(" " & inputTextBox.Text & " is within the E Range")
  End Select
```

2 variables, 1 parse or just evaluate the value and display you message as in the last one.  the main reason to save these to a variable would be if you needed the result elsewhere

Comment: I think your TryParse is backwards.  Shouldn't it be `Integer.TryParse(inputTextBox.Text, theValue)`?

Answer (score 2):

```
    Select Case Integer.Parse(inputTextBox.Text)
        Case 70 To 100
            MessageBox.Show("Your Grade is A")
        Case Is > 60
            MessageBox.Show("Your Grade is B")
        Case Is > 50
            MessageBox.Show("Your Grade is C")
        Case Is > 45
            MessageBox.Show("Your Grade is D")
        Case Is > 40
            MessageBox.Show("Your Grade is E")
        Case Is > 0
            MessageBox.Show("Your Grade is F")
        Case Else
            MessageBox.Show("Only values within 0 and 100 are allowed, please type a number within this range.")
    End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just parse the input text box once, and replace *every* instance of Range_A, Range_B, Range_Check etc. with just plain Range, so:

```
Dim Range As Integer

Range = Integer.Parse(inputTextBox.Text)

If Range >= 101 Or Range  < 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show(" Only values within 0 and 100 are allowed, please type a number within this range.")
End If

If Range >= 0 And Range <= 39 Then
        MessageBox.Show(" " & Range  & " is within the F Range")
End If
```

... and so on for all the checks.  Having separate names for these does not do anything.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that all subsequent `>=` checks are redundant. We already checked that the value is between 0 and 100. No need to see `If Range >= 0`. Just need to make sure that the code exits in time when a check fails.